# Inconsistent tracking reporting for SFMC triggered sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, triggered-send

We have have an API call for a number of our triggered sends that are transactional based. The issue I'm having is that every time I run a tracking reports for the triggered send, the email(s) on the report change.

Also, due to inadvertent influx triggering of the triggered sends, I've gone ahead and paused it. After reviewing the queue, a similar story...the queue when exported on a number of different occasions, had different email addresses.

Clearly there is something that does not make sense here. The API call includes the correct customer key, dynamic email address (for the call), but one thing to note is that the subscriber key isn't unique, meaning on every call, there is a static subscriber key. Just worth a mention in case that context is directional.